# addSubview doesn't work with newly created scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uilabel, addsubview

```
//ScrollView Creation
var scrollviewsub = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: Int(self.view.frame.size.width)-40, height: Int(self.view.frame.size.height) - 80))
scrollviewsub.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
scrollviewsub.layer.masksToBounds = true
scrollviewsub.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scrollviewsub.isHidden = false
scrollviewsub.isScrollEnabled = true
self.view.addSubview(scrollviewsub)
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: scrollviewsub)
var scrollsub = 0

//Label Creation
let dynamicLabelsub = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 30))
dynamicLabelsub.textColor = UIColor.black
dynamicLabelsub.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
dynamicLabelsub.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
dynamicLabelsub.text = "\(self.num)" + "." + "\(questno) " + subque
dynamicLabelsub.tag = uniqueid
dynamicLabelsub.isHidden = false
dynamicLabelsub.numberOfLines = 0
dynamicLabelsub.sizeToFit()

// Label Insertion 
scrollviewsub.addSubview(dynamicLabelsub)
scrollviewsub.bringSubview(toFront: dynamicLabelsub)
```

The code above shows the processes involved in making a scrollview (which appears / shows on the screen). The label view  unlike the scrollview doesn't appear. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add that scroll view in your view?

self.view .addSubview(scrollviewsub)
and change the label color to white or something it will be visible, both view and label is of same color

because I run your code and it working, adding the scollview and label also

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I had an issue with my code where a while loop was creating multiple scrollviews which overlap each other and thusly, the table could not be seen. Kudos!